Unpivoting datetime columns to rows Snowflake
I have data that looks like this:



ID
act1
act1_st
act1_end
act2
act2_st
act2_end




1
A
1/1/21 08
1/1/21 09
B
1/1/21 10
1/1/21 11


1
C
1/4/21 08
1/4/21 09
B
1/5/21 10
1/5/21 11


2
A
1/2/21 08
1/2/21 09
B
1/3/21 10
1/3/21 11


2
B
1/6/21 08
1/6/21 09
NULL
NULL
NULL



I would like to transpose the start and end times, as well as the corresponding act_ID:



ID
act_ID
start
end




1
A
1/1/21 08
1/1/21 09


1
B
1/1/21 10
1/1/21 11


1
C
1/4/21 08
1/4/21 09


1
B
1/5/21 10
1/5/21 11


2
A
1/2/21 08
1/2/21 09


2
B
1/3/21 10
1/3/21 11


2
B
1/6/21 08
1/6/21 09



I have been attempting to use unpivot, for example unpivoting all of act1_start and act2_start into a 'start' column, but having trouble joining the start end times such that the start is before the end, and the act_ID is linked to the correct interval.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Hi - Please update your question with the SQL that you've managed to write so far

SELECT ID, activity, start_time, end_time
FROM (
SELECT ID, act1, act1_st, act1_end, act2, act2_st, act2_end
FROM activities
)
UNPIVOT (
(activity, start_time, end_time) FOR activity_details IN (
(act1, act1_st, act1_end) AS 'Activity 1',
(act2, act2_st, act2_end) AS 'Activity 2'
)
);

I would use a simple union:
select id, act1 act_ID, act1_st start, act1_end end
from table
union all
select id, act2, act2_st, act2_end
from table
where act2 is not null

